Use method of undetermined coefficients to solve $y’’+4y=\sin^3(x)$
I solved for the homogenous solution and got $C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)$ but I don’t even know where to start for the particular solution. I tried guessing $A\sin^3(x)+B\cos^3(x)$ but this didn’t work. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Undetermined coefficients is admittedly a not-good choice. Does the exercise require it? If not, variation of parameters is better.

Hint: Use trig identities to convert $\sin^3x$ into some linear combination of $\sin(3x),\sin(x)$, etc just like how $\sin^2x$ is a linear combination of $\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(0x)$

Ninad Munshi's comment for sure can solve it. Or you can try Wronskians' method as well.

So let's find the particular solution by differential operator.
$$
(D^2+4)y_p=\sin^3x=\frac14\Bigl(3\sin(x)-\sin(3x)\Bigr)
$$
\begin{align}
y_p&=\frac34\Im\left\{\frac{1}{D^2+4}e^{ix}\right\}-\frac14\Im\left\{\frac{1}{D^2+4}e^{3xi}\right\}\\
&=\frac34\Im\left\{e^{ix}\frac{1}{i^2+4}\right\}-\frac14\Im\left\{e^{3xi}\frac{1}{(3i)^2+4}\right\}\\
&=\frac{\sin(x)}{4}+\frac{\sin(3x)}{20}.
\end{align}

N9t enough work shown on this question to merit an answer.

Yes, I agree with you. I might be too eager to encourage new students to raise good questions.

Depends what you mean by "good question." Answering simple homework question encourages more asking of homework questions.

@MathArt Your way is too advanced. He asked for a simple method.

Since
$$(\sin^3x)''=6\sin x-9\sin^3x$$
by looking at the given ODE, we guess that
the particular solution is in the form
$$y_p=A\sin x+B\sin^3x.$$ Then it is not difficult to find that $A=\frac25$, $B=-\frac15$.
Or as Ninad suggested in the comments, we use the triple angle formula $\sin^3x=\frac34\sin x-\frac14\sin3x$, to guess the particular solution. Due to the method of undetermined coefficients, it is in the form
$$y_p=A\sin x+B\cos x+C\sin 3x+D\cos 3x.$$ This way takes more time. We find that $A=\frac14$, $B=0,$ $C=\frac1{20}$, $D=0.$
